# Why don't count the elements of array?

Tags: iphone, ios

In the file there are 9 dictionaries each with two keys. I want to obtain an array of dictionary.I get that array elements are: 0
This is the code:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"List" ofType: @"plist"];

 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please confirm your path is valid (not nil) and show the contents of your plist in xcode.

Comment: Pl. check that link and comment whether your problem has been solved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Array"];
```

Hope this helps

Your plist is an dictionary not an array. So check this out.

Comment: Thanks, I have wrong the root of plist. I was write </dict> and not </array>. Thank you very much

Comment: Ya.. This was only example. Accept it if that helped you.